# Why does my app works on local but not with Heroku?

Tags: symfony, heroku, token

I'm doing an app with Symfony and MySQL. Everything works localy but I have a problem when I want to deploy it with Heroku.I have an error 500 with this message in the logs :

```
2021-10-19T07:50:08.112271+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.25.112 - - [19/Oct/2021:07:50:08 +0000] "GET /mon-compte/mes-emprunts HTTP/1.1" 500 3208 "https://agile-reaches-89145.herokuapp.com/mon-compte" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36   
2021-10-19T07:50:08.112595+00:00 app[web.1]: {"message":"Stored the security token in the session.","context":{"key":"_security_main"},"level":100,"level_name":"DEBUG","channel":"security","datetime":"2021-10-19T07:50:08.108221+00:00","extra":{}}
```

I see the problem is with a token and the session. But I don't know what it means.

Here is my .env

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=8f463379d965345950d4de046c122da9
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/mybibliotheque?mysql-10.4.20"
#DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

How can I fix this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you share you ENV variables or at least explain which one you have configured?

Comment: I added my .env to my question

Comment: On Heroku you have to set you ENV variable manually: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard. There are not loaded from you .env file. You should also follow this guide here to make sure you configured everything right: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-symfony4

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try to modificate the ENV